# Integration of discounted normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Hi

I want to find expectation of integration of normal distribution $\varphi(t)\sim N(0,\sigma\sqrt t)$

but i also want to discount it continuously with parameter $\alpha$.I mean i need to calculate

$E[\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\varphi(t) dt$]

This question arised from this situation: I forecasted prices,and i supposed that the error of this forecast is distributed normally $\varphi(t)\sim N(0,\sigma\sqrt t)$ Then i wanted the expectation of the prices discounted to today(t=0).But i couldn't find the error term's expectation. I hope i am clear..Thanks

Thanks for your responds

Comment: Perhaps your meaning is not clear?  How are the various random variables $\phi(t)$ dependent on each other?  If each $\phi(t)$ has mean zero, why is your $E$ not also zero?

Comment: This question would be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com - please see http://mathoverflow.net/faq

Comment: Are you saying for each $t$ you have a normal random variable $\varphi(t)$?  Then $E \varphi(t) = 0$ so your integral is 0.
But maybe you had something else in mind.

Comment: I am guessing that the OP is asking for the expectation of the Laplace transform of $\exp(-x^2/\sigma).$ Also voting to close.

Comment: The following comment was posted by Michael Hardy: In conventional usage, $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2t)$ would mean $X$ is a random variable with expectation 0 and variance (not standard deviation) $\sigma^2$. But I suspect what Yahya means is that $\varphi$ is the density function. It is somewhat conventional to use a lower-case $\varphi$ for that. My suspicion is that he want to know $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t} \varphi(t)\;dt = \int_0^\varphi(t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}\;\sigma t} \exp\left( \frac{-1}{2} \frac{-t^2}{2\sigma\sqrt{t}} \right) \; dt. $$

Comment: In my comment, I intended $\int_0^\infty \varphi(t) \cdots\cdots$, not $\int_0^\varphi (t)\cdots\cdots$.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your responds actually..Can we say that we can take expectation inside of integration so that our integral becomes "0"?

This question arised from this situation: I forecasted prices,and i supposed that the error of this forecast is distributed normally $\varphi(t)\sim N(0,\sigma\sqrt t)$

Then i wanted the expectation of the prices discounted to today(t=0).But i couldn't find the error term's expectation.

I hope i am clear..Thanks

Comment: @Yahya: is Michael hardy correct in his guess of what you want to know?

Comment: I really don't get it.

Also what are the conditions that satisfy

integral of expectation= expectation of integral ?

Comment:  I think Michael's guess is wrong. I have a random process x s.t. $x(t)\sim N(0,\sigma\sqrt t)$ where 0 is the mean and $\sigma\sqrt t$ is the standard deviation.Then I want to calculate the discounted expected value of this process. The main problem is that the t term in the variance makes x a Wiener process for which reimann integral is not defined. So how can I calculate $E[\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha t}x(t) dt$
